# Connect 2 windows in qt

Tags: qt

I dont know if this is already answered. I am a newbie to Qt. my need is to copy the value of a line edit of 2nd form to a variable I can use in the 1st form. This copying has to happen once the user types the value in the line edit and presses OK pushbutton in form 2.

form 1 is my main window of type QWidget
and form 2 is QDialog    if it really matters

Thanks for your time.
Regards
Shree

Comment: Please refer to Qt's [**Signals and Slots**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mechanism.

Comment: @Tay2510 Thanks for the quick reply.. I m trying all sorts of possibilities. I know to work with SIGNALS and SLOTS if there is only 1 widget. 2 connect between 2 widgets is what is my problem. It would be nice if you explain me that clearly. I am working on a time bound project.

Comment: What you already have tried? Show some code (SSCCE). It would be nice, if you will try something by yourself, before asking.

Comment: I tried creating a pointer to widget 2 in the **private:** of widget 1. I read somewhee that the widget 1(main widget) is to be let known that widget 2(in my case QDialog) exists. But I am not getting how to accomplish this